# How do I avoid ClientAccess error on Heroku Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

Tech stack: node/js, knex, pg

Issue:  On my local machine, my api works fine.  Migrated to Heroku, using a Heroku Postgres database.

Testing so far:

- Adding an endpoint that returns JSON without touching the database works without error.
- Attempting to reset in knex, there is a file pg_hba.conf that is missing an entry.  Although this looks like a candidate for causing this error, I see no current way to view it, let alone edit it.
- Deleting and re-creating the database changes the credentials but not the error.

Postman Request: GET http://node-express-postgres-neometau.herokuapp.com/api/ipsource
(both HTTP and HTTPS return the same error)

**code executing:**

```
 router.get("/", (req, res) => {
   ipsource.getAllIPSource()
     .then(data => {
         res.status(201).json(data);
       }).catch((err) => {
           res.status(500).json({
              message: "Undefined error on server.",
               error: err
           })
       })
})
```

**error returned:**

```
"error": {
        "length": 168,
        "name": "error",
        "severity": "FATAL",
        "code": "28000",
        "file": "auth.c",
        "line": "496",
        "routine": "ClientAuthentication"
    }
```

I have not changed anything from default settings; the tutorial I'm following (April 2020) didn't need to change anything.

There was an earlier error where the table was not defined, created the table via Heroku CLI and inserted a trial row.

What settings do I need to change where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the PostgreSQL server does not accept connections from your host using this database and user name.

You will have to add an appropriate entry to the `pg_hba.conf` file in the PostgreSQL data directory and reload PostgreSQL.

Comment: I found out how to log into my dyno, but I don't seem to have access to the /var/lib/pgsql/10/data directory.  (where the error logs seem to indicate this file lives)